# LLDB custom debug visualizer for Qt types

Tags: c++, lldb

I am trying to visualize QJsonArray (among many other types) and struggling with retrieving element data that's not simple types. For example nested arrays.

```python
    class qJsonArray_SyntheticProvider:
        def __init__(self, valobj, internal_dict):
            self.valobj = valobj
    
        def num_children(self):
            try:
                s = self.valobj.EvaluateExpression("size()").GetValueAsUnsigned(0)
                return s
            except:
                return 0;
    
        def get_child_index(self,name):
            try:
                return int(name.lstrip('[').rstrip(']'))
            except:
                return None
    
        def get_child_at_index(self,index):
            if index < 0:
                return None
            if index >= self.num_children():
                return None
            if not self.valobj.IsValid():
                return None
            try:
                element_type = self.valobj.EvaluateExpression("at(%d).type()" % index).GetValueAsUnsigned(0)
                if element_type == 1:
                    element = self.valobj.EvaluateExpression("at(%d).toBool(false)" % index)
                elif element_type == 2:
                    element = self.valobj.EvaluateExpression("at(%d).toDouble(0)" % index)
                elif element_type == 3:
                    element = self.valobj.EvaluateExpression("at(%d).toString()" % index)
                elif element_type == 4:
                    # doesn't work -> array type
                    element = self.valobj.EvaluateExpression("at(%d).toArray()" % index)
                elif element_type == 5:
                    # doesn't work -> object type
                    element = self.valobj.EvaluateExpression("at(%d).toObject()" % index)
                else:
                    return None
    
                return (self.valobj
                    .CreateValueFromData("[%d]" % index, element.GetData(), element.GetType()))
            except:
                return None
```

example c++ code:

```cpp
        QJsonArray arr;
        arr.push_back(1);
        arr.push_back("test");
        QJsonArray nested_arr;
        nested_arr.push_back(3);
        arr.push_back(nested_arr);
```

Is there a simpler way of doing it? I am not sure `EvaluateExpression` is the right goto, but I don't know how to retrieve data in other way.

Result (note the 3rd element shows up as empty array):
[image: Result (note the 3rd element shows up as empty array):]

p.s. this also happens with custom (non-Qt) types that don't have a field, just a `getSomething()` property.

edit:
this is summary provider:

```python
def qjsonarray_summary(value, unused):
    num_elements = value.EvaluateExpression("size()").GetValueAsUnsigned(0)
    return "(%d elements)" % num_elements
```

Comment: There is apparently also a "summary provider" for QJsonArray that seems to think the array nested in the `arr` variable has `(0 elements)`, so that agrees with the synthetic child provider that thinks there are no elements.  It does seem to be right about `arr` & `nested_arr`'s element count, so that indicates maybe something funny goes on with nested arrays?  Maybe investigating why that summary provider is also "wrong" will tell you what's going on.

Comment: added summary provider code

Comment: Your summary calls GetValueAsUnsigned(0) w/o checking the error return from the EvaluateExpression.  EvaluateExpression returns an SBValue, and you use SBValue.errror.success to check whether the expression succeeded.  If not the SBError's `description` will tell you what the failure was. As it stands, you can't tell whether that expression returned an error, or it really had 0 elements (I'm guessing the former...)

Comment: BTW, on the more general question of calling functions in expressions...  You have to be careful with that.  If you call an expression that takes locks, the expression may not be able to make progress w/o letting some other thread run.  And if that happens, you can get into the disconcerting state where "switching threads in the debugger" causes the thread you came from to make progress.  Also, since the debugger often has no way of knowing whether an object is initialized or not, your expressions might crash and if the take a lock and crash, your app will be leftin a bad state.

Comment: It's also somewhat slow if you have lots of these variables, but computers are pretty fast these days so YMMV on whether that matters or not.  But for sure, if you can get to the data you want by accessing ivars, your formatters will be more robust and performant.

Comment: @JimIngham you are right I get this error when inspecting 3rd element: 
`
error: error: expression failed to parse:
error: <lldb wrapper prefix>:43:1: use of undeclared identifier '$__lldb_class'
$__lldb_class::$__lldb_expr(void *$__lldb_arg)  
` not sure what that means though?

Comment: That's a part of lldb's machinery for running the expression "as if the code had been inserted, compiled & run at the current pc".  For implicit references to "this" to work, lldb needs to emulate the current class context, which it does by making a fake `__lldb_class` typedef, setting that to the actual current class, and running the code in an artificial method of that class.  For some reason lldb can't reconstruct the current context's class, though I don't see why that is happening for one of these evaluations and not the others.

Comment: Sometimes there are a couple of errors that get reported, and the inability to get the class may be a follow on error.  Be sure to scan all the errors returned to see if this is the only one.